# Complex header in data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

[image]I have json in the following format

```
[{"Employe": "",
"otherinfo": "",
"details": {
    "E": "1",
    "B": "1",
    "M": "0",
    "SR": "Yes"
}
}]
```

I want to populate the data table....how to do it...

```
var Table = $('#Table').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "Script/values.json",
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bAutoWidth": true,
    "aoColumns": [

                    { "mData": "Employee" },
        { "mData": "otherinfo" },
                    { "mData": "details" },
                    { "mData": "E" },
           { "mData": "B" },
           { "mData": "M" },
           { "mData": "SR" },
                ]
});
```

it's not coming correctly...what wrong here

I think something like this might help

```
                 { "mData": "details"
                            {
                                "mData": "E",
                                "mData": "B",
                                "mData": "M",
                                "mData": "SR"
                             },
                    },
```

Comment: What not correcly show pls explain..

Comment: check the img i just added

Answer (score 0):

```
{ "mData": "details.E" },
{ "mData": "details.B" },
```

Comment: Can you post the full working answer? I have the same issue and I can't figure it out the answer form this.. Thanks!